# Execute SQL Server stored procedure in Crystal Reports before generating the report

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using CR9 and I want to call database stored procedure from Crystal Reports before generating the report (result of this procedure will be part of report).

Is this possible and if so how to do it?

EDIT:

I want to make sequence:
1. CR call stored procedure

2. Stored Procedure (SP) generate barcode
3. SP insert generated barcode to database

*[SP also return result (1 -ok/0 -nok), but that is only info]*

4. Crystal Report put my barcode from database into report (linked as other data in report)
5. my printer print report with barcode

Comment: Can you be more specific? In what way is the SP result going to be part of the report?

Comment: I have clarified the question

Comment: In what way is your report getting the barcode from database in step 4? A typical sql command?

Comment: Standard way: I added table with that barcode to CR, and link it by id with other table. When I got record with condition base.bar_id=barcode.id, barcode is going to report

Comment: Can you accomplish the actions required for steps 4 and 5 with a sql script? If yes, try to execute the SP for steps 1-3 as a sql Command for main report and the script for steps 4-5 as a sql command for a subreport you will add in your main report

Comment: I separate it to 'steps' and try to call SP from CR. Report is generated, but in database I haven't got a barcode. It looks like SP wasn't executed

Comment: If this method seems ok for you in theory, we'll need to check each part of  its execution. Can you please show to us the code of the two SPs and some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is no solution, because my Stored Procedure call external CLR based procedure. SAP (Crystal Reports producer) confirmed that CR 9 don't support CLR based procedures, even as part of standard SP. Thanks for help @jambonick